# Fetch callback in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a simple print run statement to ensure the callback is working correctly.

```
var CsvUpload = React.createClass({
  uploadfile: function() {
    console.log('trying')
    var file = this.refs.file.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('files', file)

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_csv_to_db', {
      method :'POST',
      body : formData
    })
    .then(() => {console.log('this worked')})
    .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4 className='sub-header'>CSV Upload</h4>
        <form onSubmit = {this.uploadfile} encType="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="file" ref="file"/>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

On the server:

```python
@app.route('/add_csv_to_db', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_rows():
    file = request.files['files']
    x = io.StringIO(file.read().decode('UTF8'), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(x)
    for row in csv_input:
        if row[0] == 'Email':
            pass
        else:
            print(row)
            tasks.add_User(row)
    print('completed')
    return json.dumps('success!')
```

I see "completed" print out in the server.

In the console I see `"trying"` but it doesn't print `"This worked"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try putting in a .catch() on the promise to see if an error is getting kicked back? If there is an error, the .then() will not be called

Comment: updated the question and added a .catch() Did I do it right? nothing is being printed either :/

Comment: yup that looks good. I think it's on the server side. Your react code looks fine to me. Try hitting that method with Postman (or any API testing tool) and see what you get back.

Comment: hmm...but the server is printing "completed" and returns some Json data. I'm not getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding submission event as your uploadFile function's parameter and then calling preventDefault() on it? Your app might be refreshing on submission, and that is why you never see "this worked" printed out.
This is what I mean:

```
var CsvUpload = React.createClass({
  uploadfile: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('trying')
    ...
```

Comment: ahh, that worked. I will have to look up preventDefault() :-)